# I'm always taking photos (present progressive usage)

Tags: adverbs, present-continuous

A book for improving your speaking skills teaches that you have to use **present progressive** to sound more **impressive** instead of **adverbs**, as for the frequency of a hobby. Like this:

> Question: what is your hobby? And how often do you do it...
>
> Answer#1(adverb): I like photography. I **often** take pictures when I go out.

Or

> Answer#2(present progressive): I like photography. **I'm always taking** pictures

I don't get it. How did it become more impressive than adverbs?

Comment: The first version sounds better to me. What book did this come from?

Comment: "you have to use present progressive to sound more impressive" - As a native English speaker, I don't understand this.  There's nothing particularly "impressive" about the present progressive.

Comment: To all, it's collins speaking for IELTS... I'd say the book is good enough and I've just downloaded from the net coz' a british council lecturer recommended it from Youtube. Anyway, this query that I am asking here is what strikes me wonder why is that too...

Comment: Another is, when you use ALWAYS+ING, there's a possibility that there is a negative connotation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just me, but using progressive **does** sound more impressive to me. In fact, it's not just because of the progressive form of the verb. It's also because of using "**always**".

> Answer#2(present progressive): I like photography. I'm always taking
>   pictures

Using simple present seems to be completely correct in your sentence, but it somehow feels like you are just informing about something, but when you use an adverb like "**always**" + "**present progressive**", your way of speaking somehow involves a feeling of excitement and seems to be warmer and more inviting, which makes your sentence sound more impressive.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get the point! The message is amplified if you add feelings to that always+progressive thing.